# I keep getting "The type or namespace name 'Mvc' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)"

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, tfs

I am running a build via TFS 2010 for my MVC3 project, but it fails with the message;

Controllers\AccountController.cs (5): The type or namespace name 'Mvc' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

How do I fix this?

Comment: Is the TFS server on a different box? If so, is MVC3 installed on that box?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should install ASP.NET MVC 3 on your TFS build server. Otherwise it won't be able to compile your ASP.NET MVC 3 projects. Once you install it the `System.Web.Mvc` assembly will be deployed in the GAC and TFS will be able to compile the application.